# facebook og:meta not being recognized

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-opengraph

Okay... so we were able to get Facebook to properly display og:meta data for the like button, but the comments feature still isn't working for us.  We did see that we were having issues with the doctype and char encoding, which we have fixed.  But as I said, the comments function still isn't using the og:meta data.  here is our code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>White Coat Rack w/ Shelf : Personalized Step Stool : Gifts for Kids : Name Puzzle Stools</title>
<meta name="DESCRIPTION" content="ItsJust4me.com - personalized gifts for all ages! Personalized Step Stools, Personalized Puzzle Stools, Personalized CD, Personalized Books, Personalized Crayola Gifts, Personalized NFL Gifts, and more!">
<meta name="robots" content="INDEXFOLLOW">
<meta http-equiv="CONTENT-LANGUAGE" content="English">
<meta name="robots" content="INDEXFOLLOW">
<meta name="REVISIT-AFTER" content="1">
<meta name="RATING" content="General">
<meta name="ObjectType" content="Document">
<meta name="Revisit" content="1">
<meta name="CLASSIFICATION" content="Advertising">
<meta name="Distribution" content="Local">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.itsjust4me.com/usermods/_INCstyles_.css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.itsjust4me.com/usermods/stylemy.css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.itsjust4me.com/usermods/timer.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.itsjust4me.com/usermods/ajax.js"></script><meta property="og:title" content="Name Puzzle Stool">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.itsjust4me.com/Products/CoatRacks/White_Personalized_Coat_Rack.html">
<meta property="og:type" content="product">
<meta property="og:description" content="ItsJust4me.com - personalized gifts for all ages! Personalized Step Stools, Personalized Puzzle Stools, Personalized CD, Personalized Books, Personalized Crayola Gifts, Personalized NFL Gifts, and more!">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.itsjust4me.com/prodimages/CoatWhiShe_lg.jpg">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>White Coat Rack w/ Shelf : Personalized Step Stool : Gifts for Kids : Name Puzzle Stools</title>
<meta name="DESCRIPTION" content="ItsJust4me.com - personalized gifts for all ages! Personalized Step Stools, Personalized Puzzle Stools, Personalized CD, Personalized Books, Personalized Crayola Gifts, Personalized NFL Gifts, and more!">
<meta name="robots" content="INDEXFOLLOW">
<meta http-equiv="CONTENT-LANGUAGE" content="English">
<meta name="robots" content="INDEXFOLLOW">
<meta name="REVISIT-AFTER" content="1">
<meta name="RATING" content="General">
<meta name="ObjectType" content="Document">
<meta name="Revisit" content="1">
<meta name="CLASSIFICATION" content="Advertising">
<meta name="Distribution" content="Local">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.itsjust4me.com/usermods/_INCstyles_.css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.itsjust4me.com/usermods/stylemy.css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.itsjust4me.com/usermods/timer.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.itsjust4me.com/usermods/ajax.js"></script><meta property="og:title" content="Name Puzzle Stool">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.itsjust4me.com/Products/CoatRacks/White_Personalized_Coat_Rack.html">
<meta property="og:type" content="product">
<meta property="og:description" content="ItsJust4me.com - personalized gifts for all ages! Personalized Step Stools, Personalized Puzzle Stools, Personalized CD, Personalized Books, Personalized Crayola Gifts, Personalized NFL Gifts, and more!">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.itsjust4me.com/prodimages/CoatWhiShe_lg.jpg">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="231280463620932">
</head>
<body onload="GetCurrentTime();GetSpecialInfo();">
<div id="livezilla_tracking" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="fb-root"></div><meta property="fb:app_id" content="231280463620932">
</head>
<body onload="GetCurrentTime();GetSpecialInfo();">
<div id="livezilla_tracking" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

We are also able to finally get Facebook to scrape the page... but still no luck with the comment http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.itsjust4me.com%2FProducts%2FCoatRacks%2FWhite_Personalized_Coat_Rack.html

Comment: I've checked the content-length header, and its there... also, I added the html namespace, still no luck...

Comment: Try clicking "See exactly what our crawler see". That should help with some errors.

Comment: I did, and I get is a blank page... nothing more

Comment: Well, that is your problem then. Facebook can't crawl you. Do you have a robots.txt or something like that?

Comment: I do.. and I completely removed it just to test, but still no luck with the debugger...

Comment: So an update - I added the meta tag to our template file as static meta and it seems to work for the like button on the page, but not for the comments box... any thoughts?

Comment: You are loading the js sdk twice, aren't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the error is complaining that you haven't specified an `og:url` tag - why not do that and see if it fixes it?

Also, possibly unrelated, but the `<meta>` tags should be lowercase. Dunno if Facebook validates them that way, but worth a try.

Comment: it's definitely just missing the `og:url` as specified in the error message

Comment: I added the og:url tag and also made all the meta tags in lowercase... still no luck..

Comment: Looking at your page source, you have some javascript before your opening `<!DOCTYPE>` tag. All that stuff should be in the `<head>` at least. Try that?

Comment: @MattAndrews Just moved the scripts to the head section... still nothing... same error.  Are you guys seeing the same error if you run the URL through the linter?

Comment: Yeah, it appears that way for me too. Really odd, it looks like you have everything right. It could be another validation error, try running your site through some of the W3C HTML validation tools and see if there's anything catastrophic in there that could be causing Facebook's validator to hang.

Comment: @MattAndrews upon further review... we're having some issues with the site where even though we have added the content-type meta tag, it just doesn't seem to register with the validator... I'm thinking that might have something to do with it

Comment: Have a look at correcting some of the errors here: http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http://www.itsjust4me.com/scripts/prodView.asp?idProduct=26 (particularly the first few)

Answer (score 1):

You're never closing your `meta`-tags, you should try that for all of them.

```
<META NAME="robots" CONTENT="INDEXFOLLOW, " />
```

Also you should set the `og:url` tag if the Linter complains ;)

Comment: just added the ` />`, but still no luck, same error... it seems I can't make any headway with FB... I've also added the og:url tag, but it still won't recognize it